# Shiboken installation attempted twice

Tags: ros, homebrew, osx, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On OSX, brew shiboken installation is attampted twice via rosdep.  The second installation fails, and quits the dependency installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53400/shiboken-installation-attempted-twice/) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's still possible to run the rosdep (dependencies) installation again after the failure.  The second time around, no more shiboken installations are attempted.  Shiboken has already been installed at this point, and does not show up as a dependency.  However, it would be nice to eliminate this failure.

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-26**:
you should file a ticket for that. @WilliamWoodall where do you recommend?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-26**:
This is the appropriate issue tracker: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-26**:
rosdep should check that each dependency is *still* not installed before trying to install it, in this case shiboken is being installed for pyside and *then* rosdep trys to explicitly install shiboken again.

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-24**:
Sorry for the delay.  Do you still need me to create an issue in github?  I didn't know ROS answers doesn't auto-subscribe me to my own Questions.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-25**:
I don't see one, you can open one if this is still an issue for you.

**Comment by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on 2013-03-25**:
I will create an issue.  It looks like I did run into the same problem again while trying this new installation.